# Hill's function for translational regulation

Tags: mathematical-models, theoretical-biology, gene-regulation

Transcriptional regulation is generally modeled as a Hill's function (similar to Michaelis-Menten Kinetics):

$$\frac{dm_X}{dt}=\alpha _{m_X}.\frac{R}{K+R} -\beta _{m_X}.m_X$$

Where $m_X$ is the mRNA for some gene-$X$, $R$ is a Regulator $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are formation and degradation rate constants respectively. This equation denotes a saturation kinetics; increasing activator wont cause indefinite increase in transcription. Sounds logical because all promoter sites will be occupied at some point.

In case of a repression the equation looks like:

$$\frac{dm_X}{dt}=\alpha _{m_X}.\frac{K}{K+R} -\beta _{m_X}.m_X$$

I want to model **repression of translation** using a **similar equation**. However, the issue is that even though a single mRNA can be saturated by a regulator, increasing mRNA will require more regulators. So effectively the regulator available for a single mRNA molecule will be total regulator **÷** total mRNA.

My question is that whether in such a case the following equation is logical:

$$\frac{dX}{dt}=\alpha _{X}.m_X.\frac{K}{K+R/m_X} -\beta _{X}.X$$

Where $X$ is the protein.

Which means we are taking into consideration the effective concentration of a regulator per mRNA. In other words the Hill's constant $K'$ should scale with mRNA concentration. ($K'=K\times m_X$)

**Assumptions**:

- Well mixed system
- System at thermodynamic limit
- Amino-acid pool infinite
- Ribosomes infinite

Comment: I am confused are we talking about regulating translation or transcription? By translation for example there can be [competitive inhibition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_inhibition) caused by RNA intereference afaik, so it does not depend only the amount of mRNA... And ofc there is a max speed which depends on ribosome count.

Comment: Oh no no.. No complications involved. This is just some regulator (mechanism unknown). Ribosomes are plenty (they are not considered variables). I mentioned transcription so that those who have seen that equation for transcription regulation can draw parallels with the equation that I mentioned.

Comment: Ohh okay. So ribosome count can be considered infinite in this case, and only mRNA count and the regulator affects the speed of the translation. Am I right? If yes, then please edit your question with these details!

Comment: Does X mean the amount of proteins in your equation?

Comment: See the edit. "Speed of translation" is not affected; just the rate of protein formation.

Comment: Yepp you are right they are different things. :-)

Comment: For me it makes sense if we are not talking about ribosome count, and we assume that the regulator instantly finds free mRNAs (and if R regulates the translation in your equation). Now I think these constraints taking us far from reality, but who knows...

Comment: It can be assumed that ribosomes are not limiting. If they were then protein synthesis would be globally affected which doesn't generally happen during the usual gene regulation (happens under drastic conditions such as UPR and stress). Regulator may not instantly find mRNA. We can adjust the rate constants accordingly. My doubt was mainly regarding normalizing regulator concentration with total mRNA for the hill's equation

Comment: I checked some articles, and almost all of them use `f(r), r = (mx, X)` to describe regulation and they are talking about regulatory networks. So you'll probably need Fourier transformation and such nice mathematical tools to understand them.

Comment: Articles about regulatory models of transcription and translation - http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1204/1204.5941.pdf - http://arbor.ee.ntu.edu.tw/~brdai/papercollection/Bioinfo/chenmg99.pdf - http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/22/14/e489.full.pdf+html - http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.100.9757&rep=rep1&type=pdf - http://psb.stanford.edu/psb-online/proceedings/psb03/dehoon.pdf - http://www.uv.es/gfl/documentos/TIG.pdf - http://www.ihes.fr/~zinovyev/papers/MorozovaRNA2012.pdf - as far as I understand none of them used your approach by translation...

Comment: It _looks_ right to me. I don't have references at hand right now, but iirc even Hill functions in the context of deterministic models assume the ratio of TF concentration to the number of TF binding sites to be large; otherwise, you would have to consider binding ratios even at the level of transcription modeling, similarly as to what you are doing now for translation. E.g. consider a hypothetical situation where 10 TF molecules would compete for binding to 5 different promoter regions, each having 10 binding site repeats. (cont.)

Comment: Similarly, in your specific case, introducing the ratio of regulator per each mRNA may not even be necessary if this ratio is large, effectively leading to saturation levels anyway. If this assumption cannot be made, then your reasoning makes sense. One thing you could consider doing is establishing system reactions, then deriving Hill-free ODE equations according to the law of mass action; you could then compare this model to the one you propose. Furthermore, performing a stochastic simulation might make sense (I can recommend tools if desired). Let me know if you need help with any of this.

Comment: @w128 Thanks for the answer. I have also been discussing this issue with my PI and he also said that adding scaling in the equation is not necessary if the dynamics are not very different from unscaled one. I would do stochastic simulations later. Thinking of using fortran for implementing Gillespie's algorithm. Can you post this as an answer because this seems logical. You can add some logical/mathematical explanation. I don't need references (I don't think anyone has modeled translational regulation as saturation kinetics). PS: If you do it in 24h you will get the bounty :)

Comment: @w128 "*Similarly, in your specific case, introducing the ratio of regulator per each mRNA may not even be necessary if this ratio is large, effectively leading to saturation levels anyway*".. I agree but unlike promoter sites the mRNA concentration is not static and so the number of mRNA-sites will keep changing with change in mRNA levels. That's why I thought scaling should be important. Otherwise the model would mean that the regulator is just repressing the ribosome allocated to this mRNA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your logic looks correct to me. Essentially, what you are doing is uniformly distributing the regulator among the available mRNA.

Note that even when using Hill functions to model transcription, the ratio of transcription factor (TF) concentration to the number of TF binding sites must be large - otherwise, you would have to consider binding ratios even at the level of transcription modeling, similarly to what you are doing now for translation. E.g. consider a hypothetical situation where 10 TF molecules compete for binding to 5 different promoter regions, each having 10 binding site repeats - you need to somehow distribute the available 10 TF molecules among 50 target binding sites. Clearly, this is not something accounted for by the standard Hill equation, which would in such case wrongly assume that 10 TF molecules are regulating each construct.

In your specific case, introducing the ratio of the regulator per each mRNA may not even be necessary if this ratio is large, effectively leading to saturation levels anyway. Note that the maximum level that $m_x$ can reach (at steady state) is equal to $max(m_X) = \frac{\alpha_{mX}}{\beta_{mX}}$. If you can ensure this value to be much smaller than your translational regulator concentration, you will get similar results even if you use simply $\frac{K}{K+R}$ for translation modeling.

If the latter assumption cannot be made, then your reasoning makes sense. For each individual mRNA molecule:

$$\text{X produced per mRNA} = \alpha_{X} .\frac{K}{K+R'}$$

where $R'$ is the amount of mRNA bound to this molecule. If $R$ is the total available regulator concentration and uniform binding affinity is assumed, this means that $R'=\frac{R}{m_X}$. Summing this over a total of $m_X$ mRNA and considering degradation yields exactly your final ODE.

Note that another important assumption you are making is that regulator binding/unbinding to/from mRNA is fast compared to translation, and that no cooperative interactions are present.

If you want to verify things further, you could establish system reactions, then derive Hill-free ODE equations according to the law of mass action. You could then compare this model to the one you propose. Furthermore, performing a stochastic simulation might make sense. If you want to go down this road but don't want to implement Gillespie's algorithm on your own, you can use e.g. [SGNSim](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~sanchesr/SGN/SGNSim.html) or [COPASI](http://www.copasi.org/tiki-view_articles.php).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This was helpful. I understand that there are many considerations to be made to make the right model. I had to simulate different kinds of regulatory motifs so I wanted to keep the equations simple while at the same time allowing saturation.